# What character might "lia" [Ĩia⁵³] meaning "lick" be?

Tags: characters

I have this dictionary entry from《广安方言与民俗词典》:

> □
>
> lia3
>
> ①指舔、舐的意思，用舌头接触东西或舔吃东西。②也指巴结，讨好。例：他最喜欢lia3有权有势的。“lia3 lia3糖”，指棒棒糖。例：拿颗lia3 lia3糖去让他含倒，哄倒起莫哭。

I have seen lia3 substitued with:

> 甪

and

> 

While  does share the idea of brown-nosing (巴结，讨好) it's unlikely that it would mean lick.

Maybe a mutation of  would make more sense especially with the whole 湖广填川 thing.

Any ideas?

Comment:  http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/8365/  lick/lap with tongue

Comment: The closest thing I found was a [Thai word for *lick*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B5%E0%B8%A2#Thai), but Zhuang people are not known to be widespread in the Guang'an area. BTW many of these topolect slangs are never ever written, as is tradition to write only Classical Chinese.

Comment: @droooze Yeah, I get that, I've just seen the assumption of none over something fail many a time. I've seen a lot of Zhuang characters used in Sichuanese before, so you never know. I'd like to see your findings.

Comment: CTRL+F "riz" in [this document](https://github.com/cjkvi/cjkvi-dict/blob/master/sawndip.txt). *I think* "riz" is supposed to be the Zhuang version of that Thai word. Some of those characters look plausible, but I can't find any further information on most of them.

Comment: @droooze  and ⿰舌厘 could be good contenders.

Comment: I came across [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A8#Vietnamese) the other day, they might be etymologically related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/8365/
>
> laai2
>
> lick/lap with tongue
>
> *This character is used in Cantonese, not Mandarin/Standard written Chinese.*

someone's 鞋 = "to lick someone's boot" = brown-nosing

Comment: Any Cantonese dialects pronunciation of  close to lia?